# How should I Install a Java desktop application into a Desktop without Netbeans/IDE and MySQL?

Tags: java, desktop-application

Hi I am planning to install a Java Desktop Application to a PC that doesn't have a Netbeans IDE and MySQL installed.

Can you teach me what to do? I really don't have any clue.

Please help... thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: It might be better if you specified all the pre-requisites that a user would need for running your software on a standalone machine? The need for a Java runtime environment and a MySQL database installation is quite evident; would there be other libraries? More importantly, is a manual installation process as simple as dropping a JAR into a path and running it? Does this app need configuration parameters to be specified in a property file? I could think of more conditions, but you might want to provide more details of a manual installation process. Some parts could be automated but not others.

Comment: If all you need is a database with your program, then consider using one written in Java.  If it can be enclosed with your program your distribution problem might most likely be orders of magnitudes smaller.  For a pure Java installation, look at Java WEb STart

Comment: Some helpful details may now be found in the [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only use Java Web Start for my Swing applications.

Follow these links to start getting your head around JWS.

[Lessons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/)

[How is it launched](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml)

Answer (score 2):

I have created multiple `.jar` files before with Netbeans. Works nicely, same as an `.exe` file (double click to run).

Here is a full [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) from Netbeans. Look carefully, there is a few things one needs to alter and set before you build your project for it to function perfectly.

http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html

One thing, the user will have to have Java RE installed on his machine.